# Importing gradle dependencies

Tags: java

I'm editing an open source package which uses gradle for building/dependency management. I have not used gradle before.

I wanted to use a few jackson methods, so I added `compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.7.5'` to the `build.gradle` file and added `import com.fasterxml.jackson.*;` to my project.

But when I try to build with `./gradle shadowJar`, I get the following error:

```
Installing pre-commit hook for Unix/OS X
WARNING: jar does not create an executable jar. Use shadowJar instead.
:compileJava
/Users/mttjone/sw/builds/bixie-vanilla/src/main/java/bixie/checker/reportprinter/JSONReportPrinter.java:11: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.*;
^

...

4 errors
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

By popular demand:

```
if(JavaVersion.current() < JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7){
    println("\t************************")
    println("\t*** Hello from Bixie ***")
    println("\tYou will need Java 1.7 or higher if you want to continue.")
    println("\tYour Java is really old. Found version " + JavaVersion.current())
    println("\t************************")
    throw new GradleException("Update your Java!")    
}

import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

//install the commit hook if possible.
def hook_folder = new File('./.git/hooks')
def hook = new File('pre-commit.sh')
def installed_hook = new File('./.git/hooks/pre-commit')

if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
 println("Installing pre-commit hook for WINDOWS")
 if (hook.exists() && hook_folder.exists() && !installed_hook.exists()) {
  exec {
   commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'copy', hook.getAbsolutePath(), installed_hook.getAbsolutePath()
  }  
 }
} else {
 println("Installing pre-commit hook for Unix/OS X")
 if (hook.exists() && hook_folder.exists() && !installed_hook.exists()) {
  exec {
   workingDir '.'
   commandLine 'cp', hook, installed_hook
  }  
 } 
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'com.github.kt3k.coveralls'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
//apply plugin: 'jdepend'


apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}


def version = '1.0'
jar.archiveName = "bixie_dyn.jar"
shadowJar.archiveName = "bixie.jar"
mainClassName = "bixie.Main"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name 'Shadow'
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.kt3k.gradle.plugin:coveralls-gradle-plugin:2.0.1'
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.2'
    }
}

configurations{
  common
}

dependencies {
    compile 'args4j:args4j:2.32'    
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-actors:2.11.7'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'net.sourceforge.findbugs:annotations:1.3.2'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.7.5'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')    
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"  // Or whatever version
}


// building the jar ---------------------

jar {
  println("WARNING: jar does not create an executable jar. Use shadowJar instead.")
    baseName = 'bixie'

    from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }

    from('src/main/resources'){ include('log4j.properties')}
    from('src/main/resources'){ include('basic_prelude.bpl')}
    from('src/main/resources'){ include('java_lang.bpl')}



    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName,
                   'Class-Path': '.',
                   'Implementation-Title': 'Bixie',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

shadowJar {
    append('src/main/resources/report_html.zip')
}


//jar.dependsOn shadowJar

// testing related activities -----------------
tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "medium"

    findbugs.excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/config/findbugs/excludeFilter.xml")

    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
 }



jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/coverage"
    }
}

test {
  jacoco {
    enabled = true
  }

    testLogging {
        events "failed"
        exceptionFormat "full"
    }

    useJUnit()
}

task selfCheck {
  group 'Verification'
  description 'Run Bixie on itself.'

  doLast {
    def bixieJar = shadowJar.archivePath
    def bixieDir = compileJava.destinationDir
    def bixieClassPath = compileJava.classpath.asPath
    //TODO generate this.
    def bixieReportDir = "${buildDir}/reports/self_test.txt"

    exec {
        workingDir '.'
        commandLine 'java', '-jar', bixieJar, '-j', bixieDir, '-cp', bixieClassPath, '-o', bixieReportDir, '-checker', '3'
    }

  }
}

task inferCheck {
  group 'Verification'
  description 'Run Facebook Infer on this project.'

  doLast {
    println("REQUIRES Infer TO BE IN YOUR PATH.")

    exec {
        workingDir '.'
        commandLine 'infer', '--', 'gradle', 'clean', 'compileJava'
    }

  }
}
```

Relevant bit of gradle dependencies:

```
runtime - Runtime classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- args4j:args4j:2.32
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
+--- org.scala-lang:scala-actors:2.11.7
|    \--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7
+--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7
+--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1
|    \--- junit:junit:4.10
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
+--- net.sourceforge.findbugs:annotations:1.3.2
\--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.5
     +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.0
     \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question has nothing to do with Gradle but just with getting your code corrected.

Does the package `com.fasterxml.jackson` really exist?
Note, just that the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` or `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` exist says nothing about the package `com.fasterxml.jackson`. Those three packages are absolutely unrelated and standalone. There is no such thing like a "sub-package".